# Tableview scrollToRow(at:at:animated) causing scrollViewDidScroll(_) to be called multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have checked all possibilities as to why my UITableView is behaving so oddly for the whole day. Finally, right now I noticed something strange. I needed some help in figuring out if what I noticed is true or the problem could be in someplace else.

So in tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:), I want to scroll to a particular cell after resizing the heights of all the cells. (I am increasing the heights of all the cells.)

This is a small relevant part of my scrollViewDidScroll(_) method body that is responsible for deciding which part of the section of screen was tapped (I need this for some other stuff to work):

```
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {        
   let touchLocation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.location(in: containerView)
   let touchX = touchLocation.x
   print("X: \(touchX)")
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Now in my didSelectRowAt, when I call scrollToRow as:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```

I get this as output:

> X: 132.0 *(old touch x)*
> X: 130.66665649414062 *(old touch x when scrolling stopped)* 
> X: 188.66665649414062 *(new touch x of tap)*
> X: 188.66665649414062 *(not sure why this was printed again)*

But now when I execute the scrollToRow as:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

> X: 160.3333282470703 
> X: 160.3333282470703 *(new touch x of tap)* 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> X: 177.66665649414062 
> .
> .
> .
> *174 times*
> .
> .
> .
> X: 177.66665649414062

This is very strange. Can someone explain why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollViewDidScroll` gets called every frame that the scroll view has scrolled, doesn’t matter if it’s done by the user or by calling scrollTo methods. This can be up to, I think, 120 times per second while the user is scrolling.

If you want to do something when the scroll view has stopped, you should use the `didEndDeccelerating` and `didEndScrollingAnimation` delegate methods.

Comment: But then why does it remember the X location of touch each time? Is there any way to consume the touch event so that the next time value of X is 0?

Comment: I would guess that it resets only when the dragging starts. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I solved the issue. Thanks for the answer. I had to add a flag to prevent the code inside didScroll from being called again and again. Then after scroll ended, I turned the flag off.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for before answer.
maybe this will help,
scrollViewDidScroll every time when you scroll tableview so, may be you have to use `scrollViewDidEndDragging`,`scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating`,`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm calling!